# Compile Time Parameter for Macro Expansion

Tags: scalameta

I would like to write an annotation macro that adds an `extends <sometype>` to traits where `<sometype>` can be specified at compile time.

How can a compile time parameter be passed to a macro expansion? Ideally I would like to specify a command line argument at the compiler call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro annotations don't have access to the command-line flags passed to scalac. However, one possible way to achieve this might be to use system properties.

For example, in the macro annotation implementation

```
// MyMacro.scala
val someType = sys.props.getOrElse("myapp.sometype", ???)
```

Then pass the type as a command line option

```
// command-line
scalac -Dmyapp.sometype=foobar Code.scala
```

Similarly, it's possible to run `sbt -Dsometype=foobar compile`. However, note that the JVM process needs to start with the system property flag, so setting `scalacOptions += "-Dsometype=foobar"` may not work.

Comment: I updated the answer to mention that `scalacOptions += "-Dfoobar=yyy"` may not work, contrary to a note in my original answer

Comment: Have you guys tried `javaOptions += "-Dfoobar=yyy"`?

Comment: See https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/issues/840#issuecomment-299962849 for related discussions and an alternative workaround to use sys.props